# Does your body type affect the rate at which you age

Tags: senescence

Out of the 3 body types: ectomorph, endomorph and mesomorph, does one age quicker/slower than the others or does it not matter so much?

There are many factors that affect the rate of ageing, but I'm just wondering if body type plays a role.

I've read that humans age slower due to a slower metabolism, so does that mean that ectomorphs have, on average, live longer or is there something about endomorphs that means they live longer?

Comment: Welcome Pencilcase. We are expected to show the results of our own investigations into a subject here, you can [edit] to tell us what your searches found and where the sticking points are. You should also take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to the ways of any site you post on. Enjoy the Stackexchange network.

Comment: The term endo/meso/ectomorph just describe shape, vaguely. These are not strict nor scientific definitions. Your question would be better posed by asking whether BMI, body muscle percentage, fat percentage, height or weight affect aging. I would also advise you to define what you mean by 'aging', which itself is poorly understandable. Do you mean life expectancy? Do you mean actual well-being (what kind?), or the incidence of specific aging diseases?

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering!

I'm not a biologist but I think by ectomorph I mean people with a high metabolism and a lower percentage body fat and by endomorph I mean someone who puts on weight easier and has a slower metabolism (so generally a higher fat percentage.)

I heard that the reason why humans age slower is due to a slower metabolism and I want to know if that means ectomorphs live longer than endomorphs or if there's something else at play.

And by ageing, I mean how quickly it takes for damage to accumulate (eg: does one experience more inflammation or take longer to repair)

Comment: @Pencilcase I have never heard words like 'ectomorph', 'endomorph' and 'mesomorph' used in a scientific sense. Even whether such things as 'body types' exist is doubtful.